# Using find and exec to create directories and then work with relative path to that directory

Tags: macos, bash, find, xargs

I have a bunch of .emlx Apple Mail files in structured folders, which I would like to import into Apple Mail. I know I can do this manually, by renaming the folder to folder.mbox, and then placing the .emlx files in a nested folder called "Messages."

I have hundreds of these folders, so I'm attempting to do it with bash instead of manually.

I can set up the basic structure like so:

```
find /path/to/folders/* -type d -exec mv {} {}.mbox \; -exec mkdir {}.mbox/Messages \;
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to move the .emlx files into the newly created subfolder. I tried this:

```
find /path/to/folders/ -name \*.emlx -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ./Messages/
```

... which I figured was a long shot, but surely there's some way of dealing with the list of files that `find` generates relative to each result's path.

Comment: example paths would be helpfulö

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
find /path/to/folders/* -type d \
        -exec mv {} {}.mbox \; \
        -exec mkdir {}.mbox/Messages \; \
        -exec sh -c "mv {}.mbox/*.emlx {}.mbox/Messages" \;
```

This worked for me in my test environment — in terms of the it gave me the results I expected — but it also got a warning from `find` which I don't like (not least because I'm not quite sure why it gave the warning).

So, I would create a shell script which I called `fixmbox`, and have `find` run that for each relevant directory.  Here's the trace.  The `messages.tgz` file contains a copy of the 'starting point' directory structure; the `reset` script removes the changed directories and reinstates the originals from the tar file.  My prompt is `Osiris JL:`.

NB: I added the `-name 'm?'` condition to avoid problems with processing the current directory `.`; you probably don't need that.

#### Using `doit-all-in-one`

```
Osiris JL: reset
Osiris JL: ls -R
doit        doit-all-in-one fixmbox     m1          m2        messages.tgz    reset

./m1:
email-0.emlx email-2.emlx email-4.emlx email-6.emlx email-8.emlx
email-1.emlx email-3.emlx email-5.emlx email-7.emlx email-9.emlx

./m2:
email-0.emlx email-2.emlx email-4.emlx email-6.emlx email-8.emlx
email-1.emlx email-3.emlx email-5.emlx email-7.emlx email-9.emlx
Osiris JL: cat doit-all-in-one
set -x
path_to_folders=.
find "$path_to_folders" -name 'm?' -type d \
        -exec mv {} {}.mbox \; \
        -exec mkdir {}.mbox/Messages \; \
        -exec sh -c "mv {}.mbox/*.emlx {}.mbox/Messages" \;
Osiris JL: bash doit-all-in-one
+ path_to_folders=.
+ find . -name 'm?' -type d -exec mv '{}' '{}.mbox' ';' -exec mkdir '{}.mbox/Messages' ';' -exec sh -c 'mv {}.mbox/*.emlx {}.mbox/Messages' ';'
find: ./m1: No such file or directory
find: ./m2: No such file or directory
Osiris JL: ls -R
doit        doit-all-in-one fixmbox     m1.mbox     m2.mbox   messages.tgz    reset

./m1.mbox:
Messages

./m1.mbox/Messages:
email-0.emlx email-2.emlx email-4.emlx email-6.emlx email-8.emlx
email-1.emlx email-3.emlx email-5.emlx email-7.emlx email-9.emlx

./m2.mbox:
Messages

./m2.mbox/Messages:
email-0.emlx email-2.emlx email-4.emlx email-6.emlx email-8.emlx
email-1.emlx email-3.emlx email-5.emlx email-7.emlx email-9.emlx
Osiris JL:
```

#### Using `fixmbox`:

```
Osiris JL: reset
Osiris JL: cat fixmbox
for dir in "$@"
do
    echo "$dir"
    mv "$dir" "$dir".mbox
    mkdir "$dir".mbox/Messages
    mv "$dir".mbox/*.emlx "$dir".mbox/Messages
done
Osiris JL: find . -name 'm?' -type d -exec ./fixmbox {} +
./m1
./m2
Osiris JL: ls -R
doit        doit-all-in-one fixmbox   m1.mbox   m2.mbox     messages.tgz    reset

./m1.mbox:
Messages

./m1.mbox/Messages:
email-0.emlx email-2.emlx email-4.emlx email-6.emlx email-8.emlx
email-1.emlx email-3.emlx email-5.emlx email-7.emlx email-9.emlx

./m2.mbox:
Messages

./m2.mbox/Messages:
email-0.emlx email-2.emlx email-4.emlx email-6.emlx email-8.emlx
email-1.emlx email-3.emlx email-5.emlx email-7.emlx email-9.emlx
Osiris JL:
```

I prefer the second because there are no warnings at all.  Note the use of the `+` operator to `find` to make it act rather like `xargs`.  Writing a simple script like `fixmbox` and then using it from `find` (rather than trying to make `find` jump through all the hoops) seems simpler to me most of the time.  For example, the `fixmbox` script could be trivially modified to not fail if there is already a `Messages` directory inside one of the directories it is given to work with.  The `find` could be made to exclude `Messages` directories in the first place, of course; those don't need their `.emlx` files moved into yet another level of sub-directory.  Note that `fixmbox` is rather careful to ensure it will work even if there are spaces etc in the directory names; that isn't so easy to achieve with the version using `sh -c "..."` either.

(The `.emlx` files were all empty; the size of the file wasn't an issue for this problem.)

Comment: It never occurred to me that I could call a script with `find -exec`. That's really cool! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be, that you put the list of files into a file instead of handing over to xargs. After that you can iterate over them and move 'em

```
find /path/to/folders/ -name \*.emlx -print0 > filelist
for f in $(cat filelist) ; do mv $f ./Messages/ ; done
```